# How to merge two dataframes which are having duplicate values in the common column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have duplicate values in the common column of a data frame which has to be merged with another.
How can I join both of them without duplicating and without adding the columns from the other data frame?

df_1:

[image: dataframe 1]

df_2:

[image: dataframe 2]

How can I merge these 2 data frames into a single data frame without duplicate columns as the list of columns in both the data frames are same?

Expected final data frame:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Creating the first dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'Value_1': [25, 22, None, None, 10, 15],
                    'Value_2': [34, 18, None, None, 0,  12],
                    'Value_3': [58, 65, None, None, 18, 32]}
                    , index = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'D1'])
print(df_1)
```

**Output:**

```
    Value_1  Value_2  Value_3
A1     25.0     34.0     58.0
B1     22.0     18.0     65.0
C1      NaN      NaN      NaN
C1      NaN      NaN      NaN
C2     10.0      0.0     18.0
D1     15.0     12.0     32.0
```

Creating the second dataframe:

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Value_1': [15, 45],
                    'Value_2': [22, 198],
                    'Value_3': [36, 265]}
                    , index = ['C1', 'C1'])
print(df_2)
```

**Output:**

```
    Value_1  Value_2  Value_3
C1       15       22       36
C1       45      198      265
```

You might conatenate df_1 with new rows in df_2. Then update the values with those from df_2.

```
df = pd.concat([df_1[~df_1.index.isin(df_2.index)], df_2])
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    Value_1  Value_2  Value_3
A1     25.0     34.0     58.0
B1     22.0     18.0     65.0
C2     10.0      0.0     18.0
D1     15.0     12.0     32.0
C1     15.0     22.0     36.0
C1     45.0    198.0    265.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`pandas.merge` will create extra columns as it is just a join function. You can try to update the df_1 with the df_2 using `[combine_first][1]` for your requirement. This will match your index and replace the null values as in the other dataframe.

```
df_1

    Id  Value_1 Value_2 Value_3
0   A1  25.0    34.0    58.0
1   B1  22.0    18.0    65.0
2   C1  NaN     NaN     NaN
3   C1  NaN     NaN     NaN
4   C2  10.0    0.0     18.0
5   D1  15.0    12.0    32.0
```

```
df_2

    Id  Value_1 Value_2 Value_3
0   C1  15      22      36
1   C1  45     198      265
```

```
Updated_df = (df_1.set_index('Id').combine_first(df_2.set_index('Id')).reset_index().reindex(columns=df_1.columns)).drop_duplicates()
```

```
Updated_df

    Id  Value_1 Value_2 Value_3
0   A1  25.0    34.0    58.0
1   B1  22.0    18.0    65.0
2   C1  15.0    22.0    36.0
3   C1  45.0    198.0   265.0
6   C2  10.0    0.0     18.0
7   D1  15.0    12.0    32.0
```